# Iterate through a sequence of bits stored in a String

Tags: java, loops, ascii

```
String seq= "101010101";
byte[] bytes = seq.getBytes();

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    byte b=bytes[i]; 
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

It will print ASCII codes for 1 and 0, which are 48 and 49. I want to print 1 and 0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String seq= "101010101";
 char[] bits = seq.toCharArray();

   for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
                char b=bits[i]; 
                System.out.println(b);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String seq= "101010101";
char[] charArray = seq.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            char b=charArray[i]; 
            System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `b - 48` to print 1 or 0.

```
System.out.println(b - 48);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is a `String` containing the characters `0` and `1`. It is **not** a sequence of binary numbers. `getBytes()` give you the bytes of each of the characters in your `String`. What you want is to just iterate over the characters in your `String`.

```
for (char c : seq.toCharArray()) {
  System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you really want to use the following loop:

```
String seq = "101010101";
for (int=0; i < seq.length; i++) {
   String s = seq.substring(i,i+1);
   ... or char c = seg.charAt(i);
   System.out.println(s) .. (or c)
}
```

Why are you trying to use bytes?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
final int ASCII_0 = 48;
String seq= "101010101";
byte[] bytes = seq.getBytes();

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    byte b=bytes[i]; 
    System.out.println(b - ASCII_0);
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote when other people posted answers similar to this one?